# How do I highlight a region x0-x1 on a live python dash/plotly graph?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, live

I'm trying to highlight certain time regions on a live dash/plotly graph being graphed on localhost.
[Something like this is what I'm looking for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cF8Cq.png)

I've found many sources online about how to do this on a static graph. The graph I'm using is a live graph and does not have a "fig" object as seen in this static example: https://devcoons.com/plotly-conditional-area-highlight/. Basically, it appends new data to the data source dict. I'm wondering if it's possible to add a vrect to a figure when you don't have an explicit figure object. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I used

```
fig = go.Figure(*dict*)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).